Flutter tencent live stream app got crashed on release mode
I build a Live Streaming app by using tencent cloud with live_flutter_plugin package. It's working fine on debug mode, where it comes to release mode app got crashed. I tried different ways but couldn't find solution.
  void init() async {
    await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();

    await V2TXLivePremier.setLicence(Constant.licenseURL, Constant.licenseKey);

    _livePusher = await V2TXLivePusher.create(V2TXLiveMode.v2TXLiveModeRTMP);

    _livePusher?.addListener(onPusherObserver);
  }

when execute V2TXLivePremier.setLicence() function app got closed on release mode and got error like ERR :: JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: java_class == null
Can any one help me on this issue ?

To fix errors , add a -keep line in the Android Project proguard-rules.pro file. And then Sync Now:
-keep class com.tencent.** { *; }


Could you explain what it does?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
